# Shouldn't NSUserDefault be clean slate for unit tests?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing

I'm writing my first iOS unit tests (Xcode 5, iOS 6) and find that the results of the unit tests vary depending on what I've done in the Simulator lately.  E.g. I click on a user in my contacts list in the Simulator, and now my "recent contacts" data in UserDefaults has one more object than before, even when I'm running unit tests.

For unit testing, it's not clean to have random user defaults data (I'm used to RoR tests with their own clean db). Besides, I might want to test specific states like having empty "recent contacts" data.

From looking at related questions here, I seem some possible answers that I'm not happy with.

- Mock UserDefaults for the unit tests! I would have to modify many existing classes so that I can inject that mock.
- Clear or customize UserDefaults in a setUp method!  But then my data created laboriously in manual testing would be gone.
- Clear or customize UserDefaults in a setUp method **then** restore those values in tearDown!  Ouch.

These seem unnecessarily complicated for something that should be standard practice in unit tests.  I don't want to repeat myself in every unit test.  So, my questions are:

- Am I missing something desirable about the way UserDefaults are persisted from ad-hoc Simulator testing through to unit test runs?
- Is there a configurable way to fix this, say some way to set the unit test target to have different storage location for UserDefaults than when I use the Simulator to manually test?
- Failing that, is there an elegant way to do this in code?
- For example,  I could have a MyAppTestCase object inherit from XCTestCase and override setUp and tearDown methods to always set aside then restore the UserDefaults.  Is this a good idea?

Comment: You shouldnt unit test the user defaults as that is something you have no direct control over. A unit test should work on an atomic software unit itself -> no other classes or services should be involved. Your approach sounds a lot more like an integration test. The latter would commonly use mocked up interfaces.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question Till.  HOW do I do unit tests without pulling in something I have no direct control over?  I did not intend to pull in user defaults with real values.

Comment: Another solution would be to use an isolation framework like OCMock. Add a so called seam to your class as a property of type NSUserDefaults. The class under test would be initialized with standardUserDefaults stored in said property. In your test you can overwrite the defaults object with a mock/stub.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Using named suites [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24429237/1329214) worked well for me. Removing the user defaults used for testing could also be done in `func tearDown()`.

```
class MyTest : XCTestCase {
    var userDefaults: UserDefaults?
    let userDefaultsSuiteName = "TestDefaults"

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        UserDefaults().removePersistentDomain(forName: userDefaultsSuiteName)
        userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: userDefaultsSuiteName)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the closest to clean solution that I've seen.  Too bad I'm not programming for iOS any more!

Comment: I would love to know why this accepted answer doesn't have any upvotes, personally.

Comment: @Hyperbole This answer is 2 years younger than the most voted for answer. It was probably not the original accepted answer and is still playing catch up. Give it a couple more years, and it might be in the lead :-)

Answer (score 23):

Available iOS 7 / 10.9

Rather than using the standardUserDefaults you can use a suite name to load your tests

```
[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"SomeOtherTests"];
```

This coupled with some code to remove the SomeOtherTests.plist file from the appropriate directory in `setUp` will archive the desired result.

You would have to design any objects to take your defaults objects so that there wouldn't be any side effects from the tests.

Comment: This is the approach I've gone with and it works really well. I have a service that uses user defaults and it has an `init` method that allows the user defaults instance to be "injected". This makes it easy to unit test the service. **To purge settings from the user defaults**, use the method `removePersistentDomainForName:`. This is easier than monkeying about on the disk with plist files.

Answer (score 20):

As @Till suggests, your design is probably incorrect for good testability. Rather than having unit-testable pieces of the system read `NSUserDefaults` directly, they should work with some other object (which may talk to `NSUserDefaults`). This is roughly equivalent to "mocking `NSUserDefaults`", but is really an extra abstraction layer. Your configuration object would abstract both `NSUserDefaults` and other configuration storage like keychain. It would also ensure that you don't scatter string constants around the program. I've built this kind of config object for many projects and highly recommend it.

Some would argue that unit-testable objects shouldn't rely on singletons like `NSUserDefaults` or my recommend global "configuration" object at all. Instead, all configuration should be injected at init. In practice, I find this to create too much headache when interacting with Storyboards, but it is worth considering in places where it can be useful.

If you really want to dig deeply into `NSUserDefaults`, it does provide some layering capability. You may investigate `setVolatileDomain:forName:` to see if you can create an extra layer for your unit test. In practice, I haven't had much luck with these kinds of things on iOS (more-so on Mac, but still not to the level you would need to trust it).

It is possible to swizzle `standardUserDefaults`, but I wouldn't recommend this approach if you can avoid it. Your "save everything at start and restore everything at end" is probably the best standardized way to approach the problem if you can't adapt your design to avoid externalities.

Comment: +1 for proper and verbose answer - the abstraction layer indeed is something that is a great approach. I found unit tests often force me to build much better software just because I am forced to build things in a way that allows proper unit-testing  -  despite the fact that those tests are pretty helpful ;).

Comment: I was expecting this to be a configuration/environment issue the way it is in other frameworks (for example, RoR default is to create a perfectly clean db every run).  Failing that, I agree with you about adding an abstraction layer.  thanks.

Comment: Singleton swizzle may become mandatory at some point of your project. http://twobitlabs.com/2011/02/mocking-singletons-with-ocmock/

Answer (score 5):

I like to create a new one so there's no collision

```
import XCTest

extension UserDefaults {
    private static var index = 0
    static func createCleanForTest(label: StaticString = #file) -> UserDefaults {
        index += 1
        let suiteName = "UnitTest-UserDefaults-\(label)-\(index)"
        UserDefaults().removePersistentDomain(forName: suiteName)
        return UserDefaults(suiteName: suiteName)!
    }
}

class MyTest: XCTestCase {

    func testOne() {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.createCleanForTest()
        XCTAssertFalse(userDefaults.bool(forKey: "foo"))
        userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "foo")
        XCTAssertTrue(userDefaults.bool(forKey: "foo"))
    }

    func testTwo() {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.createCleanForTest()
        XCTAssertFalse(userDefaults.bool(forKey: "foo"))
        userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "foo")
        XCTAssertTrue(userDefaults.bool(forKey: "foo"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily save & restore the persistent domain for the main bundle's identifier, which is what `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:forKey:]` writes to. For example,

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *originalValues = [defaults persistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];

// do stuff, possibly [defaults removePersistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]]
// or using setPersistentDomain: to substitute a dictionary of mock values and test against that

[defaults setPersistentDomain:originalValues forName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
```

You can also use `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] volatileDomainForName:NSRegistrationDomain]` if you want to access a single combined dictionary of the stuff you register using all the `-registerDefaults:` calls (at least for any code that has run up to where the unit test has started, of course).

Answer (score 1):

While I believe the [Rob Napier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19084715/2567725) is the most reasonable, for those who needs just a quick-fix, here's my workaround:

```
class MockUserDefaults: UserDefaults {
    private var dict: [String: Any?] = [:]
    override func set(_ value: Any?, forKey defaultName: String) {
        dict[defaultName] = value
    }
    override func value(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        return dict[key] ?? nil
    }
}
```

Cons:

1. works only with `String` keys, unless you implement all needed types
2. supports only runtime storage unless you dump it to some file.

Pros:

1. is agnostic of "Logic tests"/"Host application tests".
2. works perfectly for run-time, so should work in a lifetime of a single test func.